# Not Able to click on "Search" button Selenium Web Driver Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on "Search" button but no luck. I also tried searching for iframe but there is no iframe.

Here is my "Search" button html tag:

```
<input type="submit" value="search">
```

Here is xpath that I am using in order to click on Search button:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mainDiv']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/blockquote/fieldset/input[1]")).click();
```

Following methods I have tried:

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement("//*[@id='mainDiv']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/blockquote/fieldset/input[1]").perform();

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavsscriptExecutor)driver; jse.executeScript("document.getElementById(//*[@id='mainDiv']/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/blockquote/fieldset/input[1]").focus().click();");

new WebDriverEait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector(Inpout.submit[value='search']"))).click();

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".submit[value='search']")).click();
```

Above method should be able to click on "Search" button.

However, I am getting exception: unable to find element with cssSelector or xpath or id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why used absolute xpath instead try relative xpath something like below

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit'])).click();
```

Comment: I am glad that it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the html tag of your "Search" button it looks Submit button of the Form present on web page. You can either use the click() method on the web element like a normal button or use the submit() method on any web element on page or on the submit button itself.

Try to locate the Search(Submit) element

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@type='submit'])).submit();
```

or you can call submit() method on any other webelement on that page.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='some_id'])).submit();
```

Comment: I tried both of them but neither worked. Then I tried relative path with .click() method and it worked.